# How to get most appeared combination using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table storing log entries, a simplified version would be

```
key value
a   1
a   2
a   3
a   2
b   1
b   2
b   2
```

and I just want to extract the most appeared combination like:

```
key  value
a    2
b    2
```

since `a-1` and `a-3` combination come up only once, and `a-2` combination is twice.

any kind of SQL solution is welcomed, I just want to know the gist to tackle this issue, I will find the right solution for my own platform / sql variant.

---

based on Gordon Linoff's great answer and the abilities my platform can provide, I end up using something like this:

```
select 
  key,
  value
from (
  select
    key,
    value,
    rank() over(partition by key order by t1.cnt desc) as rank
  from (
    select
      key,
      value,
      count(*) as cnt
    from 
      table
    group by
      key,
      value
  ) t1
  group by
    key,
    value,
    t1.cnt
) t2
where t2.rank = 1
```

Comment: Just wondering what you gonna do if there is a tie between combinations

Comment: @nicholasnet thanks for the heads up, I'm okay with either combination if there were a tie

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @Strawberry since it's a raw log table, there is no exactly a primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain in MySQL, but you can do:

```
select key, value, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by key, value
having cnt = (select count(*)
              from t
              group by key, value
              order by count(*) desc
              limit 1
             );
```

If you are using MySQL version 8 or just about any other database, use `rank()` or window functions:

```
select key, value, cnt
from (select key, value, count(*) as cnt,
             max(count(*)) over () as max_cnt
      from t
      group by key, value
     ) t
where cnt = max_cnt;
```

Comment: your solution is really brilliant! sadly it seems like my platform doesn't support neither `having with child query` nor `aggregate function inside window function `, I might be missing something and I will continue to investigate. anyway your solution truly inspires me, thanks a lot!

Comment: I end up using something similar but more verbose version, see my updates

Comment: @jasonslyvia . . . (1) there is no need to nest subqueries when you can include window functions and aggregation functions in the same query (but I understand why one would do so).  (2) `rank()` is a perfectly reasonable alternative to the `max()` in this query.

Comment: thanks for your kind feedback, now I realized where the redundancy of my SQL comes from

Answer (score 1):

> I'm okay with either combination if there were a tie

You could try this

```
SELECT `key`
    ,`value`
FROM t
GROUP BY `key`
    ,`value`
ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but your answer only gives me 1 combination, i.e. I will lost `b-2` combination in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DECLARE @T TABLE  (key_ varchar(10),Val int)
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 'a' Key_, 1 Val UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' k, 2 v UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' k, 3 v UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' k, 2 v UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' k, 1 v UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' k, 2 v UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' k, 2 v

SELECT T.key_,T.Val FROM (SELECT key_,Val,Row_Number()Over(Partition By Key_,Val Order By key_ ) Count_ FROM @T) T INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(Count_) Count_ FROM (SELECT Row_Number()Over(Partition By Key_,Val Order By key_ ) Count_ FROM @T)X) XX ON XX.Count_ = T.Count_
```